# How to Track All Output Files From Executable, If Possible?:

Tags: linux, file, tracking, utility

I have been assigned to a project with no documentation and lots of unmanaged code.
There are explicitly-declared paths throughout the project (and in fact, they are environmental variables that were being set to different values in different places) that point to output files. I've changed these to redirect the output to directories in my workspace, but yet the files are not produced, nor can I find them in my workspace. I believe they're being created somewhere else in the filesystem. As I mentioned before, there are many different places that the environmental variables are assigned, through the use of scripts. I thought I had gotten the relevant scripts, but apparently I am missing something.

Is there a utility I can use to track all file output from a particular executable (print out all file names read/written)?

I am working under Fedora and the project is written primarily in Fortran.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

strace will print details for every syscall, you can simply filter the output for calls to open().

Comment: Wonderful. I should have thought of that solution. I will try it out now and update my vote on your comment accordingly.

Comment: I can't say that this solution brought me the answer I wanted (don't misunderstand me; it did exactly what I needed it to do!), but it did help me identify a rather glaring issue in the software with which I'm working. Thanks for your help, tstenner.

Answer (score 2):

One option is `lsof` e.g.

```
lsof -p <PID>
```

Comment: That is a good choice when a) `strace` produces too much output for whatever reason, and b) when it is known *when* the process has the files open.

Comment: Great to know that there are other methods. I grep-ed the output from strace, but minimal output in the first place is always good.